# DG31PR intel board with 1GB RAM, can I add 2GB RAM with existing 1 GB?

Tags: memory

I have a PC with below mentioned configuration

- DG31PR intel board
- Core 2 Duo Processor
- Transend DD2 667 1 GB JetRam , JM667QLJ-1G, 240P DDR2 DIMM (128M*64) (64Mx8 DDR2 667 5-5-5) [LM]

I am planing to upgrade the RAM to increase the performance/Speed...

I searched for the Transend RAM with same series JM667QLJ-2G, but not found in flipkart/amazon. Only JM667QLU-2G available will it support my DG31PR intel board ?

Can I use it with existing 1GB Ram + 2 GB RAM (my board supports MAX 4GB, 2 Slots) ?

Please share your views...

Thanks for your time...
-SVNindia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new ram you are getting is DDR2 and is unbuffered, then your computer should accept it.

I have found the RAM specification of your board on C-net:

[image]

Don't worry if the Ram stick you are going to buy has a diffrent speed that the one stated above because they are all backward-compatible.

For more information you should visit Crucial website and click on DDR2 : http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-memory-speeds-compatability

Comment: Will the 2 slots on the board can have different RAM size on each ? 1GB on one slot and 2GB on another

Comment: @Sanjith They can run together, but there may be a performance hit of about 10 % if memory servers me right.On intels website [link](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-011965.htm) it describes your configuration ---> Flex mode.